# Variable inside a variablename?

Tags: perl

I want to check each of my 4 buttons in the **for** loop. However, I can't figure out how to run through them? :-/

**if ('$button'.$i)** seems to be the problem, but how can I write it correctly??

```
my $button1 = 0;
my $button2 = 123;
my $button3 = 0;
my $button4 = 0;

for (my $i=1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
   if ('$button'.$i) {
      print"Yes we found positive value!";
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You write it correctly by using Perl's array type.

```
my @button;
$button[1] = 0;
$button[2] = 123;
$button[3] = 0;
$button[4] = 0;

for (my $i=1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
   if ($button[$i]) {
      print"Yes we found positive value!";
   }
}
```

It is possible to use variables to construct a variable name and to access the variable's value, but that is almost always a Bad Idea.

Comment: Re "*Bad Idea*", See [Why it's stupid to `use a variable as a variable name'](https://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html) and [A More Direct Explanation of the Problem](https://perl.plover.com/varvarname2.html).

Comment: Tip: Best to start at zero, since array indexes start at zero.

Comment: Tip: Best to avoid C-style for loops in favour of much simpler foreach loops.

Comment: So, `my @buttons = ( 0, 123, 0, 0 ); for my $i (0..$#buttons) { if ($buttons[$i]) { ... } }`, or even `my @buttons = ( 0, 123, 0, 0 ); for my $button (@buttons) { if ($button) { ... } }`

Answer (score 1):

```
my @buttons = (0, 123, 0, 0);
foreach my $button (@buttons) {
    if ($button > 0) {
        # Do something
    }
    else {
        # Do something
    }
}
```

or,

```
my @buttons = (0, 123, 0, 0);
for (my $i=0; $i<scalar @buttons; $i++) {
    if ($buttons[$i] > 0) {
        # Do something
    }
    else {
        # Do something
    }
}
```

Or,

```
my @buttons = (0, 123, 0, 0);
foreach (@buttons) {
    if ($_ > 0) {
        # Do something
    }
    else {
        # Do something
    }
}
```